# how to use a string in struct in linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

In my code  I have 2 structs named `villa` and `apartment`. They have members of type `char*`. When in my void record I  get other parts of the structs like `villa1.price` (which is float) from user,It works ,but when it comes to the `char*`,I cannot read strings using `scanf("%s",&villa1.city`) and so I used another array of chars named `v1` to get info from users and then  assign it to villa1.city using `villa1.city=a1`.

This worked for the first time, but I want to make a linked list. The first time I send `villa1.city` to `insertFirstVilla` to add this to linked list it works, but when I add second node ,the `villa1.city` in first node is lost and it keeps happening every time I add a new node.

How can I get data from user like `villa1.price` or if it is not possible how to copy it in way that data remains safe when I add second node to my list.
I post a part of my code for `villa`, but the code is the same for `apartment`.

```
struct villa
{
    float built;
    float garden;
    float price;
    int floors;
    char* city;
    char* ST;
    char* alley;
    char* postal_code;
}villa1;
struct nodev
{
    villa info;
    nodev* next;
}*headv = NULL;
void insertFirstvilla(float built, float garden,float price,int floor, char*city) {
    nodev* link = (nodev*)malloc(sizeof(nodev));

    link->info.built = built;
    link->info.garden = garden;
    link->info.price = price;
    link->info.floors = floor;
    link->info.city = city;
    link->next = headv;
    headv = link;
}
void record()
{
    char a;
    printf("is the building apartment? (y/n):");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    char a1[100];
    char v1[100];
    if (a == 'y')
    {
    /*  printf("enter apartment features:");
        printf("\nenter built area:");
        scanf("%f", &apart.built);
        printf("\nenter basic price:");
        scanf("%f", &apart.price);
        printf("\nenter floors number:");
        scanf("%d", &apart.floor_no);
        printf("\ndoes apartment have elavator(if there is no elavotor enter zero else enter one):");
        scanf("%d", &apart.elevator);
        printf("\nenter city:");
        scanf("%s", &a1);
        apart.city = a1;
        insertFirstapartment(apart.built, apart.price, apart.floor_no, apart.elevator,apart.city);
        writetofilea(apart.built, apart.price, apart.floor_no, apart.elevator, apart.city);*/

    }
    else if (a == 'n')
    {
        printf("enter villa features:");
        printf("\nenter built area:");
        scanf("%f", &villa1.built);
        printf("\nenter garden area:");
        scanf("%f", &villa1.garden);
        printf("\nenter basic price:");
        scanf("%f", &villa1.price);
        printf("\nenter floors number:");
        scanf("%d", &villa1.floors);
        printf("\nenter city:");
        scanf("%s", &v1);
        apart.city = v1;
        insertFirstvilla(villa1.built, villa1.garden, villa1.price, villa1.floors, villa1.city);
        writetofilev(villa1.built, villa1.garden, villa1.price, villa1.floors, villa1.city);
    }
    getchar();
}
int main()
{
    int t = 0;
    while (t<4)
    {
        record();
        t++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag if your question is only about C. If this was indeed about C++ the answer would be use `std::string` instead of `char*`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put a little effort into grammar, spelling, and punctuation; your question is painful to read.

Comment: You do not allocate memory for your strings. You only make them point to v1, a1 buffers.

Comment: One way to do this is to set a max length for each field and allocate fixed size character arrays.  When you read, be careful to limit the size and make sure to leave room for null-termination.

Comment: You must need to learn more about pointers, dynamic memory allocation and memory release. Do you have code out of a function???? After `insertFirstvilla` code you have more code out of a function. Where is `record()` code?

Comment: @SuperG280I have learned about dynamic memory allocation recently and you're right, I certainly need more practice. sorry about `record()` I added it to code and so no more code out of function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example reading the city:

```
char a1[100];
scanf("%99s", a1);  // an array will be passed as an address, so no need for &
apart.city = malloc(strlen(a1)+1);   // ask for memory
strcpy(apart.city, a1);              // copy it
```

or use `strdup`, which does this for you:

```
char a1[100];
scanf("%99s", a1);  // an array will be passed as an address, so no need for &
apart.city= strdup(a1);              // get memory and copy it
```

Comment: after saving data in binary files, for reading them using`fread(&apart, sizeof(apartment), 1, fptr)`should I allocate memory for strings first and if so how?

Comment: And how do you write the data to the file? Pointers are not valid anymore when reading back and the data pointed to should be written separately; it is not automatically written (in C nothing is "automatic").

Comment: I used `fwrite(&apart, sizeof(apartment), 1, fptr)`  ,but when I want to read memory(when I run my code again) I receive error reading characters of string(even when I allocate memory before reading them) any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `fwrite` _does not write data pointed to by pointers._ You must write that data separately, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is deep copying versus shallow copying.

```
struct villa
{
  int floors;
  char* city;
};

villa V1, V2;
char buffer[10];
strcpy(buffer, "Venice");
V1.city = buffer; /* This copies nothing. V1.city now points to buffer. */
V2 = V1;          /* This is a shallow copy. V2.city now points to buffer. */
strcpy(buffer, "Moscow");
printf("%s\n", V2.city); /* prints Moscow */
```

Do you see the problem? If you want each villa to have a buffer of its own, you must write code to allocate and manage that memory, and if you want the copies to be deep copies, you must write an assignment operator.